# Question about the right use of coordinate system

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, coordinate-systems

My question is: If I have a particle moving in a tridimensional space while attracted by a central force $ -k/r²$, where $k$ is constant, then can I use cylindrical coordinate system to describe the equations of motion or do I have to use spherical coordinate system, given that the position on the last one is described only by $\vec{r} = r \hat{r} $?

Comment: One usually picks a coordinate system appropriate for any symmetry that might be present in the problem.  For the spherically symmetric force stipulated, the spherical coordinate system is appropriate.  For a central *line* force, e.g., a line of uniform charge density, there is cylindrical symmetry and so the cylindrical coordinate system is appropriate.  Why would you choose a coordinate system that make the problem harder to solve and/or the solution harder to interpret?

Comment: The Third Law of progress in theoretical Physics (due to S. Weinberg) states that "You may use any degrees of freedom you like to describe a physical system, but if you use the wrong ones, you'll be sorry." Just to answer your "have to" aspect of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any coordinate system you wish, however for central forces a spherical or even a cylindrical one will be more appropriate than a Cartesian system. The spherical system being the better one since it share the same symmetry as the force field.

There is an important property that central forces systems have that guides us in choosing the most appropriate coordinate system though. A particle under a central force has constant angular momentum and this implies that its motion lies in a plane containing the centre of force. We need only two coordinates to describe its motion. Hence both cylindrical and spherical coordinate systems turn out to be superfluous. The most appropriate coordinate system we can choose in this case is the polar plane one.